# How to enable touchpad clicking in fedora?

Tags: fedora, xorg, touchpad

How can I enable click feature of laptop touch pad in fedora 20?

My fedora 20 does not recognize clicking with a touch pad.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  For example:  under Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad (tab).  Is 'Enable Touchpad' checked?

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_enable_touchpad_click

Comment: It should be useful [to give a look to this link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics) and or to `man synclient` if installed.

Comment: What touchpad model do you have? If you don't know, what laptop model? What gesture are you using to click?

Comment: Are you using the `Gnome` desktop?

Comment: I'm totally newbie to linux. I dont know what exactly gnome is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is late coming but:

[image: Settings]
[image: Select Mouse & Touchpad]

Checking the select box offered the easiest most succinct resolution in my situation. Ubuntu did not require and had it automatically selected so while it was confusing, it was also easily resolved.

You may have to configure synclient but more than likely you can alleviate the issue with a few pokes around your current system settings selections.